# How to show sources as a tree structure in Firefox dev tools

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug my javascript code with Firefox developer tools. While Chromium shows the files and folders in a nice tree structure, Firefox displays all the source files in a long list, which makes it hard to find the right file.

Is there any plugin/add-on or similar for Firefox that can help to show the sources in a more Chromium-ish way?

**Sources in Chromium:**

[image: Sources in Chromium]

**Sources in Firefox:**

[image: Sources in Firefox]

Comment: Are you using firefoxs dev edition??

Comment: No. Maybe I should? :)

Comment: Well, it looks the same in dev edition anyway :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 56 (currently [Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org)) has a new debugger UI, which displays the scripts in a tree structure similar to the one in the Chrome DevTools besides other features like allowing to open several files in tabs:

[image: New Firefox DevTools debugger frontend]

Comment: And the debugger can even be run outside of Firefox as a website allowing to be used in Chrome and Opera as well. See the [GitHub website](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html) for more details.